# Indent(tab) in chrome console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I searched around but no answer -->

There is any way to enable tab for indention in chrome devtools console when i'm writing ? for example writing a function, 
I need to manually add spaces every time .

I searched in settings but nothing (chrome 50 version)

Tried tab,ctrl-tab,alt-tab.. and so

thanks

Comment: If you are using ubuntu go through this issue in github
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromedeveditor/issues/3861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you found out how to do this by now but if not it's shift + enter. I just played around with it recently and it ended up working for me.

Take care!